# How to programmatically push a ToggleButton?

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation

I have this code which can programmatically push a button, but I would like a version to work for ToggleButton.

```
public static void PushButton(Button b)
{
     ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(b);
     System.Windows.Automation.Provider.IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as System.Windows.Automation.Provider.IInvokeProvider;
     invokeProv.Invoke();
}
```

So I tried the ToggleButtonAutomationPeer...

```
public static void PushButton(ToggleButton b)
{
  ToggleButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ToggleButtonAutomationPeer(b);
  System.Windows.Automation.Provider.IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as System.Windows.Automation.Provider.IInvokeProvider;

//But invokeProv is null.   Peer is ok. 
}
```

Comment: I know that's the question but do you really need to do that? If you bind and via commands etc. you can make your life easier a bit - but I don't have the full story, just a check:)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [Toggle Button Automation Peer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.togglebuttonautomationpeer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
public static void PushToggleButton(ToggleButton b)
{
    ToggleButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ToggleButtonAutomationPeer(b);
    System.Windows.Automation.Provider.IToggleProvider toggleProvider = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Toggle) as System.Windows.Automation.Provider.IToggleProvider;
    toggleProvider.Toggle();
}
```

Comment: I get an error on `System.Windows.Automation.Provider` (`The type or namespace name 'Provider' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Automation' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`
`

Comment: It works but somehow did not have the exact same effects as pressing the toggle button by hand. Interesting pattern though, I wonder why Microsoft didn't opt to add a .Toggle() helper method :-D

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do that is by raising a ClickEvent on the button.

```
//check that the button is untoggled
if (this.MyToggleButton.IsChecked == false)
{
    //set button toggled
    this.MyToggleButton.IsChecked = true;
    //then raise a click evt
    this.MyToggleButton.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
}
```

*Assuming that `MyToggleButton` is a `ToggleButton` defined in code-behind or in xaml via `x:Name`*